# Wordpress update_post_meta – Meta data being deleted

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

SO, it seems like with a plugin of mine, the meta data at a key (let's call it "_target"), is being deleted randomly at times.

This is the line I'm using to set it:

```
update_post_meta( $id, '_target', 'test' );
```

Which works nicely. I'm calling it upon an API request. I did this by extending the WooCommerce API with a custom endpoint.

Throughout the codebase, I am *not* overwriting the _target key again excplicity.

Could there be any other way of the meta data being overwritten nonetheless?

What I am doing is overwriting other keys, such as:

```
update_post_meta( $id, '_additional', 'test' );
```

for example.

Could this lead to a side effect of the previous meta data being overwritten somehow?

Thanks!

Comment: Your code is extremely vague, and lacks context.  Can you make it more clear how you're calling these functions?

Comment: @HowardE sorry, you're right. I tried to add the fact that it's called on an API request. But besides that, there really isn't much more to it, which is why it confuses me so much!